# How to install ncurses-devel to get samtools to work?

Tags: linux, ncurses, samtools

I am on a HPC with no root access and **I cannot use the sudo** command but I am trying to get samtools-1.10 to work, unfortunately I get the error message:

```
The 'samtools tview' command uses the curses text user interface library.
Building samtools with tview requires curses/ncurses/etc development files
to be installed on the build machine; you may need to ensure a package such
as libncurses5-dev (on Debian or Ubuntu Linux) or ncurses-devel (on RPM-based
Linux distributions) is installed.
```

So I downloaded ncurses-6.1.tar.gz, I unzipped it and then used

```
./configure -prefix /home/vbuswell/programmes/ncurses-6.1
```

samtools still gives me the error

```
fatal error: curses.h
```

Any advice? Have i installed ncurses in the wrong place? or do I specifically need libncurses5-dev?

Comment: https://medium.com/@retellect/fatal-error-curses-h-no-such-file-or-directory-3468b9782ab1

Answer (score 1):

You might need sudo in order to facilitate your solution.

You’re simply missing the ncurses library. Fix by opening a terminal and typing the command below:

`$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`

If you’re using RHEL / Fedora / CentOS Linux, fix it by typing this in the terminal:
`# yum install ncurses-devel ncurses`